# Image Compression before uploading Bitmap.CompressFormat

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to compress images selected by user from gallery for uploading. I saw that my camera pictures are over 5MB and I would like to compress them(same as facebook if possible). What I've been trying:

I let the user select the photo from gallery,get the uri and use this:

```
File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), selectedImageUri));
            long length = file.length();
            Log.e("Filesize:", "Before: " + length);
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("jpg")||file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("jpeg")){
                Bitmap original;
                try {
                    original = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    length = sizeOf(original);
                    Log.e("Filesize:", "BeforeCompression: " + length);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
                    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
                    length = sizeOf(decoded);
                    Log.e("Filesize:", "AfterCompression: " + length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Filesize:", "Error: " + e);
                }
```

I did this to test if it was working first, but what I get in the console is:

```
/name.company.newapp E/Filesize:: Before: 4970874
/name.company.newapp E/Filesize:: BeforeConversion: 63489024
/name.company.newapp E/Filesize:: AfterConversion: 63489024
```

The size doesn't change at all. Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're actually getting the size of memory used by the Bitmap object by calling *sizeOf(bitmap)* and not the actual file size.

As you should know, a bitmap operates with the number of pixels in an image. Even though you compress the image using a JPEG compression, the image's width and height do not change. Thus the number of pixels do not change and thus the Bitmap's size (in memory) would not change too.

However, if you save the compressed bitmap to a location in your hard disk and use File.length() to calculate the size of the compressed image, then you will notice the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it now. I thought it wasn't working, but your answer makes sense. Can I upload it without saving to memory ?

Comment: Well. First you need to load it to memory to perform a compression. 
You can then directly compress it to a file. You can then refer the file. Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Not really, I haven't had any experience with bitmaps, but I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the size before decoding and after compression:

```
length = sizeOf(original);
```

Also i would recommend you to flush and close the outputstream:

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Hope i could help!

---

**Edit:**
Please try the following method to decode your bitmap:

```
       public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HEIGHT){
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT=HEIGHT;
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HEIGHT)
            scale*=2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

You can change the width and height of your picture to make it smaller.

Comment: But I was doing that. The point is that the size is not changing.

Comment: edit, I don't want to change the width and height. That's the whole point fo using Bitmap.CompressFormat. Please read my question.